# How do I make MonadRandom a Functor?

Tags: haskell, monads

It seems that MonadRandom from the random-fu package is not a Functor, as I am getting errors like:

```
Could not deduce (Functor m) arising from a use of ‘_1’
from the context (MonadRandom m)
```

I've tried adding the following code:

```
instance Functor MonadRandom where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative MonadRandom where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

but I get the error:

```
The first argument of ‘Functor’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
  but ‘MonadRandom’ has kind ‘(* -> *) -> Constraint’
In the instance declaration for ‘Functor MonadRandom’

The first argument of ‘Applicative’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
  but ‘MonadRandom’ has kind ‘(* -> *) -> Constraint’
In the instance declaration for ‘Applicative MonadRandom’
```

Comment: `MonadRandom` is a type-class, you can't make those instances of other type-classes.

Comment: You should add least add the function's signature, so that we know the context where you want to use `_1`.

Comment: @Xeo: actually you can, with `{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}` `import GHC.Exts` try e.g. `class Foo (c :: * -> Constraint)` `instance Foo Num`. Whether that makes any sense at all is a different question...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`MonadRandom` is a class, not a type with kind `* -> *`, like `Maybe` for example. Usually, you would use something like

```
instance MonadRandom m => Functor m where
    fmap = liftM

instance MonadRandom m => Applicative m where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

**However**, in this case the [instances of `MonadRandom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.6.0/docs/Data-Random.html#t:MonadRandom) are already functors, so now the instances are ambiguous! Instead, you should  to add the `Functor` constraint at your function:

```
yourFunction :: (MonadRandom m, Functor m) => ...
-- instead of yourFunction :: (MonadRandom m) => ...
```